# All row corresponding to null value rows are disappeared after using CAST or SAFE_CAST function in BigQuery

Tags: casting, null, type-conversion, google-bigquery-storage-api

I have issue with CAST or SAFE_CAST a table in BigQuery from string into INT64 or FLOAT64.

I have a csv file which contains timestamp %m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p such as **10/25/2023 03:42:00 PM**
So that file cannot be uploaded normally to BigQuery.

Then I tried to upload the file manually with all column **with string schema.**

The file would look like this (example of 3 columns):

Id   Date                  Fat
1234 10/25/2023 03:42:00 PM 25
1234 09/15/2023 05:15:00 PM null

**The Fat column only contains interter data as 25 and 22 and null value.**

So after upload this file, I tried to create new table based on that file by using conversion functions on BigQuery to covert each column's schema.

Id was CAST from string to **INT64** (Interger)
Date was change from string to **DATETIME** by PARSE_DATETIME
and then Fat column by CAST OR SAFE_CAST function with expect it would change from string to INT64 or FLOAT64.

Everything seems work well as I saw Id was converted to INT64 and Date become DATETIME data.
However all rows corresponding to the null data in **Fat** column were ****disappeared ** in the new table**

Does anyone know what happened and how can I deal with this issue to create a new table which contains all data as the original csv file?

Comment: Finally, I found the way to soled this issue :)